# Heroku deployment rake db:create/migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am following Hartl's ROR tutorial and I am trying to get my DB working on Heroku, but to no avail.  When I run the following commands:

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

or

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get the following errors:

```
Running `rake db:create` attached to terminal... up, run.5477
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory

Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5562
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory
```

I am using `postgresql` for `development` and `production`.  Here is my latest commit https://github.com/Euklidian-Space/sample-app

Here are the heroku logs:

```
2015-07-30T16:42:48.956556+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by gabriel.grover@gmail.com
2015-07-30T16:42:53.039994+00:00 heroku[run.5562]: Awaiting client
2015-07-30T16:42:53.090027+00:00 heroku[run.5562]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-07-30T16:42:53.343439+00:00 heroku[run.5562]: State changed from starting to up
2015-07-30T16:42:55.633768+00:00 heroku[run.5562]: State changed from up to complete
2015-07-30T16:42:55.618985+00:00 heroku[run.5562]: Process exited with status 127
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `bin/bundle`, `bin/rake`, `bin/rails` and `bin/setup` files, the first line of each reads `#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.2`. Change them all to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Then try deploying again.